# ElasticSearch and Java API - How to get rid of delay after an update

Tags: java, database, elasticsearch, nosql

Looks like I'm having some issues while updating an array. I think that my code is suffering from delay after the update. This is my code. I'm running it several times. If I put a sleep after the update, it will work. But it is not a good practice and it does not fit on my project.

```
listOne.add(peanut); // The listOne is a Set<String>

UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
updateRequest.index(aux.getIndex());
updateRequest.type(org.core.database.json.Element.classType);
updateRequest.id(elementId.toString());
updateRequest.doc("listOne",listOne); // The new doc
element.setListOne(listOne); // Sets the new list for future updates

// Retry 3 times before failing the update
updateRequest.retryOnConflict(3);
client.update(updateRequest).get(); // Updates it
```

Imagine that i want to add 10 different peanuts. I cannot do it, because with this method, ES will lose data. So I want a method that allows me to store all the data without losing one (or more) of the peanuts. (append the new peanut to the array without visiting the data stored in ES could be a good solution, but I don't know how to implement it).

The version of the ES is 2.3.4.

Thank you guys.

Comment: The problem is that you use `retryOnConflict` which will always make the latest update win. That's not what you want: peanuts might be added concurrently, so there's a race condition here. When there is a conflict, you should retry the whole process: retrieve the current peanuts, append the new peanuts, and perform the update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, I don't think that the root cause is on retryOnConflict.. I have already deleted it, and the results are pretty the same. I have to guarantee that the last array was properly updated. And after that, I'll be able to get the new array updated, and add another peanut..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using client.bulk method? That should solve your problem. And on top of it, you can use BulkRequest.refreshPolicy method to refresh Elastic as per your use-case. Looks like REFRESH_POLICY.IMMEDIATE is what you are looking for. But be careful with the cost it implies for background operations.